# Destructuring and creating a new object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a large data object I want extract some of the data for an ajax request. Using ES6 destructuring I can do this.

```
var { title, first_name, last_name, username, email, email_confirm, mobile_number, password} = this.data;
```

However I would then have to pass the fields into my ajax individually, not so bad

```
axios.post('/mypost', {title, first_name, lastname})
```

I would like to restructure this back to a new objects something like.

```
var newobject =  { title, first_name, last_name, username, email, email_confirm, mobile_number, password} = this.data;
```

Edit,

so I can do it on 2 lines

```
 var  { title, first_name, last_name,username, email} = this.data;

 var newobject =  { title, first_name, last_name, username, email};
```

Was trying  to do it one one

```
 var newobject =  { title, first_name, last_name, username, email} = this.data; //
```

Comment: just assign newobject to JSON.parse(this.data) ?

Comment: Can you create a small reproducable problem? The last snippet you posted actually works.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to get.? This code works

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to reconstruct object using:

var newobject =  { title, first_name, last_name, username, email, email_confirm, mobile_number, password};

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, just use object spread:

```
const newObject = {...this.data}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object spread :-

```
axios.post('/mypost', ...this.data)
```